# I am trying to make a color game in react but always end up with diffrent colors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## MY REACT GAME

- This is my jsx code I am trying to create a color game but my
  main_color starts from  undefined and then lags behind the main color
  array which I created and imported from  another function . I need
  help fixing my code . Can anyone help me with it

```js
import React from "react";
import "../css/App.css"
import {
  RandomGenerator
} from "../logics/Logics"
class Main extends React.Component {

  state = {

    color: "",
    main_color: ""


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let box_count = 3;
    let byee = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");
    let main_color = this.state.main_color;
    for (let i = 0; i < box_count; i++) {
      byee[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (byee[i].style.backgroundColor === main_color) {
          win();
        } else {
          loose();
          console.log(byee[i].style.backgroundColor);
        }
      })
    }

    function win() {
      console.log("winner");
    }

    function loose() {
      console.log("loose");
    }
  }
  render() {

    let newgame = () => {
      let box_count = 3;
      console.log(this.state.color);
      this.setState({
        color: RandomGenerator(box_count)
      })
      this.setState({
        main_color: this.state.color[Math.floor(Math.random() * box_count)]
      })
      let main_color = this.state.main_color;
      console.log(this.state.main_color);
      let hard = document.querySelector(".hard");
      let rgb = document.querySelector(".rgb");
      rgb.innerHTML = ` ${main_color}`
      hard.style.display = "none";
      let byee = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");
      for (let i = 0; i <= box_count; i++) {
        byee[i].style.backgroundColor = this.state.color[i]
      }

    }

    let easy = () => {
      let box_count = 3;
      let clrs = RandomGenerator(box_count);
      let hard = document.querySelector(".hard");
      let main_color = clrs[Math.floor(Math.random() * box_count)]
      let rgb = document.querySelector(".rgb");
      rgb.innerHTML = ` ${main_color.toUpperCase()}`
      hard.style.display = "none";
      let byee = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");
      for (let i = 0; i <= box_count; i++) {
        byee[i].style.backgroundColor = clrs[i]
      }


    }
    let hard = () => {
      let box_count = 6;
      let clr = RandomGenerator(box_count);
      let hard = document.querySelector(".hard");
      let main_color = clr[Math.floor(Math.random() * box_count)]
      let rgb = document.querySelector(".rgb");
      rgb.innerHTML = ` ${main_color.toUpperCase()}`
      hard.style.display = "";
      let byee = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        byee[i].style.backgroundColor = clr[i];

      }
    }


    //returning 
            return (<div>
  <div className="upper-sec">
    <p className="display-6 text-center pt-3"> The Great <br />
      <span className="rgb "></span> <br />Guessing Game</p>
  </div>
  <div className="the-line d-flex justify-content-between">
    <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary button" style={{ marginLeft: "150px" }} onClick={newgame}>New Game</button>
    <div>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-success button me-5" onClick={easy}>Easy</button>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-danger button " style={{ marginRight: "150px" }} onClick={hard}>Hard</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="box-main">
    <div className="easy mt-2">
      <div className="boxes"></div>
      <div className="boxes"></div>
      <div className="boxes"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="hard" style={{ display: "none" }}>
      <div className="boxes"></div>
      <div className="boxes"></div>
      <div className="boxes"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            )

  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if I understand what you want to do, this is your problem:

```
let box_count = 3;
console.log(this.state.color);
this.setState({
   color: RandomGenerator(box_count)
})
this.setState({
 main_color: this.state.color[Math.floor(Math.random() * box_count)]
})
let main_color = this.state.main_color;
```

You have to remember that state only gets updated once the component renders.

So calling `setState()` on the color object, then referencing it on the next line will just give you the previous value, which prior to the first render was `undefined`.

What you should do is:

```
let newgame = () => {
  let box_count = 3;
  const newColors = RandomGenerator(box_count);
  this.setState({
     color: newColors
  })
  const newMainColor = newColors[Math.floor(Math.random() *   box_count)]
  this.setState({
  main_color: newMainColor
  })
  let main_color = newMainColor;
  //.....
  for (let i = 0; i <= box_count; i++) {
     byee[i].style.backgroundColor = newColors[i]
  }
}
```